# import .so into android studio error

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, .so

I am trying to import a third-party .so into my android-studio project,but I don't know how to do.

My environment:

Ubuntu 14.04, *Android-studio* **1.4**, *Gradle* **2.4**,NDK r10e

so,Is there anyone can help me ? Thanks a lot.

what I have done:

1. download the ccv(github.com/liuliu/ccv) source code,then use arm-linux-androideabi-gcc to get the libccv.so file.
2. copy the libccv.so file into the folder /src/main/jniLibs/armeabi
3. int the main activity, system.LoadLibrary("ccv"),then call ccv's function ccv_read_impl.

but the IDE says :

undefined reference to 'ccv_read_impl'

my project structure is like this:

[my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nScle.png)

as @sonic saied ,I add System.loadLibrary("ccv") in my MainActivity, but the error is still there.

As I'm trying to use a simple .so to test how to use it.I write the C add function :int result(int a,int b),and make it libadd.so.the others are all as above;

the error info is like this: 
[the error info and the code I call the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qGKf.png)

Comment: *"didn't work for me"* is kind of vague, isn't it? Could you analyze step by step where your results differ from expected?

Comment: yes.I have edit my problem.

Comment: > but the IDE says: *undefined reference to 'ccv_read_impl'*. Where exactly does the IDE say that? Maybe the best would be to add a screenshot with this message

Comment: ok,I will post the image

Comment: What is the contents of the **jni** directory (collapsed in your [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4qGKf.png))? Does your **MainActivity.java** define `private native int result(int a, int b);`?

Comment: no,I didn't define that.It was used before for addFromC,but now it is commited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the learning curve of how to organize the environment with Android Studio, I am afraid you have a major roadblock here: the [ccv library](http://libccv.org) *[does not have a suppored Java wrapper](https://github.com/liuliu/ccv/issues/128)*. You can build the binary for Android, but you cannot call its functions directly from Java.

A generic wrapper may be a huge investment, but a great contribution to the community. On the other hand, if your app needs some very specific response from Computer Vision, you can probably forge a specialized JNI wrapper. Still, this is not a plug-and-play task.

Answer (score 2):

The resource you use seem fine.

However you should have your `.so` inside `/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7` (if the `jniLibs` or `armeabi-v7` folders does not exist, create them).

You can check if your apk package the `.so` by running `unzip -l path_to_your_apk`. You should have one line like `your_lib.so`.

Finally make sure you load your library at runtime. You should call at some point `System.loadLibrary("your_lib");`

You can also read the [NDK guide](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html) from google.